# Does C++ allow comparison between std::span::iterators when one span is a subspan of the other?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, std-span

Generally speaking C++ doesn't allow comparing iterators between different containers. For example:

```
int main() {
  std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<int> w = {4, 5, 6};
  std::cout << v.end() == w.end() << std::endl;  // undefined!
}
```

But is this true also for subspans created with `std::span::subspan()`? For example:

```
int main() {
  int a[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::span<int> s(a);
  std::span<int> t = s.subspan(1, 2);
  std::cout << t.begin() - s.begin() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `1`, which is expected, because internally iterators are probably just pointer to the underlying array. The question is: does the standard guarantee that this works correctly?

And if so, more generally, can I also compare iterators from any spans that come from the same contiguous object in memory? For example:

```
int main() {
  int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::span<int> s(a);
  std::cout << (s.subspan(1, 1).end() < s.subspan(3, 1).begin()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Added language-lawyer tag, per "does the standard guarantee"

Comment: Relevant draft section: [24.7.2.2.7 / span.iterators](https://eel.is/c++draft/span.iterators)

Comment: Compare iterators on different objets is a U.B. Trying this code with MSVC, gives the error "cannot compare incompatible span iterators" in debug, but because their are raw pointers in release the code runs fine.

Comment: Another interesting question would be whether subspan iterators can be compared to iterators from the underlying container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the standard allows this.

According to the description of *Cpp17ForwardIterator* in [[forward.iterators]](https://eel.is/c++draft/forward.iterators):

> The domain of `==` for forward iterators is that of iterators over the
> same underlying sequence.

This means that the equality and inequality operations of two iterators are *only* defined over the same underlying sequence.

In your example, the underlying sequences of the two iterators being compared are *different*, because they have different start points and different sizes, which makes comparisons no longer well-defined when one of the iterators is outside the bounds of the other sequence.

---

As mentioned in the comments, your example will trigger an assert in MSVC-STL's debug mode, which was explained by the maintainer in [#1435](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1435). Similar issues are also discussed in the Cpp Core Guidelines, see [#1157](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1157#issuecomment-380180537).

Comment: Does `std::ranges::subrange` suffer from the same issue as `std::span::subspan`? I am not sure whether I should ask a new question, but occasionally I want to do `std::prev(subrange.begin())` when I know that `subrange.begin()` does not equal the `begin()` of underlying range. Is that allowed?

Comment: I think `std::prev(subrange.begin())` is ok, because `subrange.begin()` is specified to return the underlying *original* iterator. The validity of the operation on the original iterator will not change.

Comment: "underlying sequences of the two iterators being compared are different" - that requires citation.  It is plausible that the wording is that span's underlying sequence remains the original buffer, with begin/end of the span itself being a subsequence.  It would depend on how the standard is worded.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't think the current standard clearly defines what the underlying sequence of an iterator is.  There was one in C++17: "*An iterator j is called reachable from an iterator `i` if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression `++i` that makes `i == j`. If `j` is reachable from `i`, they refer to elements of the same sequence*" but I think it could still be interpreted differently in the current context.